# What is the life time of a singleton class's member variables?

Tags: c++, memory, singleton, static-members

```
class Member {
public:
    Member(int idx) {
        this->idx_ = idx;
    }

    int get_idx() {
        return idx_;
    }

    void set_idx(int idx) {
        this->idx_ = idx;
    }

    void foo();

private:
    int idx_;
};


class SingletonClass {
public:
    static SingletonClass& GetInstance() {
        static SingletonClass inst;
        return inst;
    }

    vector<Member*> get_members() {
        return this->members_;
    }

    Member* get_member(int idx) {
        return this->members_[idx];
    }

    void add_member(Member* mem) {
        this->members_.push_back(mem);
    }

private:
    SingletonClass() {}
    vector<Member*> members_;
};

void Member::foo() {
    SingletonClass inst = SingletonClass::GetInstance();
    cout << inst.get_members().size();
}


int main() {  
    SingletonClass inst = SingletonClass::GetInstance();
    inst.add_member(new Member(0));
    inst.add_member(new Member(1));
    cout << inst.get_members().size() << endl;

    Member* mem = inst.get_member(1);
    mem->foo();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
2
0
```

It seems that when I get the instance of SingletonClass inside `Member::foo()`, the member variable vector `members_` of `SingletonClass` is cleared... Can anyone explain to me why and how this happen? And how can I fix it to get expected result? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not a singleton class if you can create multiple instances...

Comment: Just so that you understand better Brian's comment: `SingletonClass inst = SingletonClass::GetInstance();` this creates a copy of the static "singleton". (try to delete the copy constructor and initialize a reference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems that when I get the instance of `SingletonClass` inside `Member::foo()`, the member variable vector `members_` of `SingletonClass` is cleared... Can anyone explain to me why and how this happen? And how can I fix it to get expected result?

You are making a copy of the object in the following line:

```
SingletonClass inst = SingletonClass::GetInstance();
```

and then you are modifying the contents of the copy. The original object remains unmodified.

Use:

```
SingletonClass& inst = SingletonClass::GetInstance();
```

To prevent this from happening elsewhere in your code, explicitly delete the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator.

```
private:
    SingletonClass() {}
    SingletonClass(SingletonClass const&) = delete;
    SingletonClass& operator=(SingletonClass const&) = delete;
    vector<Member*> members_;
```

Comment: ^^^ and forbid copy constructors and assignment operators for singletons.

Comment: Better yet, forbid using of Singletons altogether :)

Comment: @SergeyA, Wouldn't it be nice if we could go back to all the books, magazine articles, and web pages to edit them and point out why use of singletons is a bad idea!!!

Comment: @RSahu, well, we can't go back in time, but we can correct errors. We can start our efforts with SO. :)